# sha512 support on Redhat 7

Tags: c++, g++

I installed https://github.com/herumi/msoffice on Redhat 7, by linking to my manually installed OpenSSL3 (because this herumi package uses EVP in newer OpenSSL)  It works well with the default command line option:

`bin/msoffice-crypt.exe -e -p test test.xlsx enc.xlsx`

However, when trying to choose AES256 instead of AES128, as:

`bin/msoffice-crypt.exe -e -p test -encMode 1 test.xlsx enc.xlsx`

it issues an error:

`exception:hassPassword:not support:sha512`

The above error appears to come from https://github.com/herumi/msoffice/blob/master/include/crypto_util.hpp .  However I can not figure out its exact mechanism to determine the availability of sha512, and how to fix it.  The command `sha512sum` is certainly available on the machine.

Could someone figure out how to resolve this - to allow that "-encMode 1" option, just by reading the above short hpp code?

I checked its source code and its required library https://github.com/herumi/cybozulib , to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

The author resolved the problem by a patch: https://github.com/herumi/msoffice/issues/27

Indeed, it's just a simple modification in that crypto_util.hpp mentioned in the question.